# How to recursively generate an RxJava Flowable using operators vended in the core lib?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

The simple program below eventually hangs.

```
// Kotlin
package com.example

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS

fun main() {
    fun incr(n: Int): Single<Int> = Single.just(n + 1)

    fun numbers(n: Int, max: Int): Flowable<Int> = Flowable.just(n).concatWith(
        if (n < max)
            incr(n).observeOn(Schedulers.single()).toFlowable().concatMap { next -> numbers(next, max) }
        else
            Flowable.empty()
    )

    numbers(1, 1_000_000).sample(5, SECONDS).blockingForEach(::println)
}
```

On my laptop it usually hangs somewhere after 23500, example output:

```
15945
21159
23802
```

The question is actually two-fold:

- Is it possible to recursively generate an RxJava Flowable in a stack-safe, non-hanging manner using operators vended in the core library?
- If so, what's the technique for achieving that?

Comment: Check out the [expand](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowabletransformersexpand) operator.

Comment: @akarnokd this doesn't quite address the issue. firstly, i'm interested in achieving my goal using operators vended in the core library (i'll update the description to reflect that). secondly, while RxJava is clearly not stack-safe by design, i'd really like to understand why the code above "hangs". i'd expect to see a performance penalty for trampolining between threads, but the freezing of the entire program is completely unexpected.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it creates a really long chain of subscriptions which then causes a StackOverflowError. Such errors are considered fatal and often not recoverable. In the `numbers` method, try adding `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).observeOn(Schedulers.single())` to the returned expression.

Comment: As for the recursive `Flowable`, you'll need a serialized `PublishProcessor<Flowable<T>>`, `concatMap(v -> v)` and then `doOnNext` which then signals the next `Flowable` to the `PublishProcessor`.

Comment: @akarnokd I understand the need for a "serialized" Processor, but I'm not quite clear on why `concatMap` would be necessary or why it can't just be a `*Processor<T>`

Comment: I suggested that because it gives async Ts and your question appeared to require async Ts. Of course, if you can generate Ts synchronously, you don't need `concatMap`.

Comment: @akarnokd i  see, that makes sense. could please take a look at the answer below? i'm still unclear on how/when to send the initial value. presumably that the missing piece which breaks PublishProcessor

Comment: You don't need `doOnSubscribe` with `UnicastProcessor`, just call `proc.onNext(seed)` directly from that `let` method. For `PublishProcessor`, use `startWith(seed)`.

Comment: @akarnokd ideally i'd like the logic to be general enough that it can be applied to any `FlowableProcessor`. `startWith`  or `startWithItem` works for `UnicastProcessor`, but for `PublishinigProcessor` only the first item is emitted (looks like `doOnNext` isn't being  called as expected) and with `MulticastProcessor` an NPE is thrown.

Comment: Okay. Try concatEager(just(seed), proc) instead.

Comment: @akarnokd same result. given `val proc = MulticastProcessor.create<Int>().toSerialized()`, the following produces an NPE (from MulticastProcessor.onNext(MulticastProcessor.java:297)): `Flowable.concatArrayEager(Flowable.just(1), proc).doOnNext { prev -> proc.onNext(prev + 1) }.take(10).blockingForEach(::println)`

Comment: looks like i'm probably missing a call to `start()` when using `MulticastProcessor`. still unclear why `PublishProcessor` only publishes the seed and nothing else.

Comment: I see, try `merge(proc, just())` so that proc has a subscriber when `just` signals its item and.

Comment: @akarnokd that seems to only work for the simplest case. but, if, for example, `sample` is called the following exception is thrown: `MissingBackpressureException: Could not emit value due to lack of requests` `at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.PublishProcessor$PublishSubscription.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:367)` `at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.PublishProcessor.onNext(PublishProcessor.java:242)` `at io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.SerializedProcessor.onNext(SerializedProcessor.java:103)`

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution, based on suggestions in the comments:

```
package com.example

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.processors.UnicastProcessor
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS

fun main() {
    // doesn't seem to work with PublishProcessor or MulticastProcessor
    fun <T> unfold(seed: T, next: (T) -> T?): Flowable<T> =
        UnicastProcessor.create<T>().toSerialized().let { proc ->
            proc
                .startWithItem(seed)
                .doOnNext { prev ->
                    when (val curr = next(prev)) {
                        null ->
                            proc.onComplete()
                        else ->
                            proc.onNext(curr)
                    }
                }
        }

    fun numbers(first: Int, max: Int): Flowable<Int> =
        unfold(first) { prev -> if (prev < max) prev + 1 else null }

    numbers(1, 1_000_000_000)
        .sample(1, SECONDS)
        .blockingForEach(::println)
}
```